# Django edit view does not show

Tags: django

I am new to Django.

My app allows a user to create a `project` by providing a title and a body content, delete it and update it.

Now, I am creating and edit/update view for my app but it is not showing up in my html page.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('allprojects', views.allprojects, name='allprojects'),
    path('createproject', views.createproject, name='createproject'),
    path('<int:project_id>', views.projectdetail, name='projectdetail'),
    path('<int:project_id>/editproject', views.editproject, name='editproject'),

]
```

**projects/views.py**

```
@login_required
def editproject(request, project_id):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['content']:
      project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
      project.title = request.POST['title']
      project.content = request.POST['content']
      project.developer = request.user
      project.save()
      return redirect('/projects/' + str(project.id))
    else:
      return render(request, 'projects/editproject.html', {'error':'All fields are required.'})
  else:
    return render(request, 'projects/allprojects.html')
```

**projects/templates/projects/editproject.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Edit Project{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mt-4 offset-md-3 col-md-6">
      <h2>Create a new project</h2>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Title of the project</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="1" name="title"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Brief description of this project</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" name="content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

**PROBLEM**

When I go to a urls such as `http://localhost:8000/projects/2/editproject` there is not the update form I want, the page exists but it contains nothing

Comment: Why do you use `'projects/' + str(project.id) + 'editproject.html'` as template? You likely want to use `'projects/editproject.html'`.

Comment: And in the final else block you certainly want 'editproject.html', not 'allprojects.html'.

Comment: If I do not use `projects/' + str(project.id) + 'editproject.html`, how can I be sure that I am editing the specific project with id, for instance, 2?

For example: `http://localhost:8000/projects/2/editproject` it means I am inside project 2 and I am editing project 2

Comment: You're confusing templates with URL paths. They have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I see, I think it is a Rails way of doing thing.
I understand that since in the `urls.py` I have `path('<int:project_id>/editproject', views.editproject, name='editproject')`, the template does not have to include the `str(project.id)` because it is "already included" in `path('<int:project_id>/editproject``
`

Comment: I followed your advices but still the form does not appear in `http://localhost:8000/projects/2/editproject`

Comment: The `form` method should be POST here, not PUT.

Comment: Yes, I did that but nothing show us in the `editproject` template. Even a simple h1 tag not in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the `project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)` in the dictionary in order to get the value in template.

Change your view like this:

```
@login_required
def editproject(request, project_id):
  project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['content']:
      project.title = request.POST['title']
      project.content = request.POST['content']
      project.developer = request.user
      project.save()
      return redirect('/projects/',project.project_id)
  return render(request, 'projects/editproject.html', {'error':'All fields are required.','project':project})
```

And in the `template` you can get value like this :

Also in your template change `method=put` to `method=post` 
and also you need to provide  `action` if you want to update.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Title of the project</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="1" name="title">
{{project.title}}
</textarea>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, small type in the answer `return redirect('/projects/',project.project_id)
` should be `return redirect('/projects/'+ str(project.id))
`

Comment: The only thing that does not work is the error `'error':'All fields are required.`. If I submit the form without writing anything, it should re-render it and tell me the error. It does re-render the form but it does not tell me the error

Comment: Use the `messages` for this  from`django.contrib.messages`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way in which if the users goes into the edit form, the form is already compiled with the previous input? So that the user does not have to retype everything but change the fields he wants to change

Comment: use `value={{...}}`  like this `<input type='text' name='title' value={{project.title}}>`

Comment: `<textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="1" name="title" value={{project.title}}></textarea>`but it does not work, neither does if I use `default={{project.title}}`. The form fields are still empty.

Comment: in case of `textarea` use the code i wrote above.Did you pass the `{'project':project}` through dictionary in the template